# Optimisation and a do loop c++

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization

Below is a bit of my code. It is an optimization code and I am struggling with what to write where I have put *******'s. What bit of code can I write there in order to ignore the point that i have already calculated?

```
do {

  // save the current value
  oldValue = value;
  maxValue = oldValue; // set the maxValue for the local search to be the current value

  // now look around the current point to see if there's a better one nearby
  for ( int i = -1; i <= 1; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = -1; j <= 1; j++ ) {
      // this gives 9 points including the current point (when i=0, j=0)
      if ( i==0 && j==0 ) {

      *********************************

      }
      else {
        newValue = cost(lat + step * i, longi + step * j); // value at neighbouring point
        if ( newValue <= maxValue ) { // is it bigger than maxValue?
          // yes so set maxValue and save point i,j values
          dlat = i; 
          dlongi = j;
          maxValue = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // update lat and longi to new point with lower 'value'
  lat += step * dlat;
  longi += step * dlongi;
  value = maxValue;

  //writes out
  //cout << iteration << " : " << lat << "," << longi << " : " << value << "\n";

  iteration++; // add one to the iteration counter   
}
```

Comment: First step in optimizing your code: make it readable so others can help you optimize it.  (Start by fixing indentations)

Comment: The second step, profile the program with real data to gain an insight into what is inefficent. You might very well be surprised.

Comment: _'Premature optimization is the root of all evil'_ -- Edsger W. Dijkstra _

Comment: You might want a `while` at the end there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "That's not Dijkstra, it's Knuth" - Casey

Comment: @Casey There's a lot of [arguing](http://original.jamesthornton.com/eckel/TIPatterns/html/Introduction.html) about this. Nothing definite, I personally prefer to give it to Dijkstra, and Knuth has been citing him. But the statement is important, not who brought it first!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, I've been trying to find something definitive since I posted that, and failing. I'll let you have it ;) "Casey, you are an idiot." - Casey

Comment: `if ( newValue <= maxValue ) { // is it bigger than maxValue?` No, it's smaller than `maxValue` - that's what `<=` means.

Comment: @Casey That's simply an ambiguous comment, could be read either way (check for/is true)

Comment: "Optimization" in this context refers to *finding a maximal value of a function*, not *making one's code run faster*. So that "premature optimization" thing, whoever said it, is inappropriate here. Retagged for clarity.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, the comment on the next line does say "yes" in answer to "is it bigger?". The comments are at least misleading. This is a very good example of poor commenting: the comment simply repeats what the code already says a la `x = 4; // assign 4 to x`. The whole shebang could be replaced with `// Neighboring point is a better approximation`

Comment: @anatolyg Did you mean _"Optimization"_ was meant to say solving the problem at all? Then well, yes it's not about optimization but getting it working correctly.

Comment: You should consider describing the optimization problem you are solving before spitting a bit of code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Optimisation" in this context means "writing some code to solve an optimisation problem", not "optimising some code".

Answer (score 3):

You can simply remove `if ( i==0 && j==0 )` because you don't need to compare the point with itself. Replace the `else` with `if(i!=0 || j!= 0)`.

Note that your code suffers from local maxima.

Comment: Hi what does local maxima mean?

Comment: it means that if you find no better points in the neighborhood of the current point, I suppose you declare it as maximum. (I say "I suppose" as your code lack of an exit condition, please add it). Anyway there could exist better points far from the current point and you won't never find them.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the for cycles and use -1, 0, 1, or whatever combination of them you make directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the minimum, right?  You want to set
dlat and dlong to the coordinates of the minimum, and maxvalue
to the minimum value.  (Maybe the variables should be renamed?
The variable extremalValue may be better.)  So, if point (0,0)
is the extremal value, you don't want to do anything, since you
already have the answer.  If it isn't, you don't want to do anything,
since you will change dlat, dlong and maxvalue when you find the
true extremal value.  So, just put a big, fat semicolon there.

Or write your loop so that the test is "if (i != 0 or j != 0)".

(Did you know the token "or" is equivalent to "||"?  I knew it
at one time, but I forgot, and just relearnt it.  It's the same
with "and" and "&&".  Also, user defined numeric literals are the
boss.)